# Using Altair and 'mark_point' to highlight area in a faceted graph

Tags: python, graph, altair

I'm trying to use 'mark_point' to highlight an area in a faceted graph, using Altair. Because the graph is faceted, I need to use the same dataset for plotting the points and the highlighted area. However, I have a different number of points for each panel. From what I could understand, the bands (highlighted areas) will be overlayed, according to the number of points in the dataset. This, of course, affects the opacity, [as seen here](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1302).
The graph below shows what I mean:

[image]

Is there a way to make the opacity value normalized by the number of points in each facet? Maybe plot each area individually, and decide on a different opacity value for each? If not, then can I plot the grid between the highlighted area and the points? Maybe "reconstruct" the grid by plotting multiple vertical and horizontal lines?

The code for generating the graph above, is below:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
from vega_datasets import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

source = data.cars()

# adapting data
brand = list()
for i in source['Name']:
    brand.append(i.split(' ')[0])
source['Brand'] = brand

weight = list(set(source['Weight_in_lbs']))
weightArray = np.array_split(weight, 2)
weightClassification = list()
for weight_in_lbs in source['Weight_in_lbs']:
    if weight_in_lbs in weightArray[0]:
        weightClassification.append('light')
    if weight_in_lbs in weightArray[1]:
        weightClassification.append('heavy')
source['weight_classification'] = weightClassification

# remove empty columns
source = source.dropna(subset=['Horsepower', 'Brand', 'Origin', 'weight_classification'])

# define colors and shapes for weight_classification
colors = {"light": "green", "heavy": "steelblue"}
shapes = {"light": "circle", "heavy": "square"}

# define chart
chart = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x=alt.X("Brand:N", title=None, axis=alt.Axis(labelAngle=-90), scale=alt.Scale(padding=1)),
    y=alt.Y("Horsepower:Q", axis=alt.Axis(title='Horsepower', titleFontSize=17)),
    color=alt.Color("weight_classification:N", scale=alt.Scale(domain=list(colors.keys()), range=list(colors.values()))),
    shape=alt.Shape("weight_classification:N", scale=alt.Scale(domain=list(shapes.keys()), range=list(shapes.values()))),
    tooltip=['Name', 'Origin', 'Horsepower', 'Miles_per_Gallon']
)

# plot yellow band with mark_rect
yellow_band = alt.Chart(source).mark_rect(
    color='red',
    opacity=0.01,
).encode(
    y=alt.datum(100),
    y2=alt.datum(140),
)

# combine the all charts
final_chart = alt.layer(
    yellow_band,
    chart
).properties(
    width=alt.Step(25),
    height=350
).facet(
    'Origin:N',
).resolve_scale(
    x='independent'
).configure_axis(
    grid=True
)


final_chart.save('AltairCar.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the x-axis would be quantitative, you could use `mark_area` instead of `mark_rect` [like in this example](https://joelostblom.github.io/altair-docs/gallery/falkensee.html), but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do that when the axis is nominal...

One workaround here is to pick a lighter color and use full opacity so that there is no difference between the stacked and unstacked rects, e.g. `color='#f19f9f'`.

Comment: I considered the option of using a lighter color and full opacity, but this would block the grid. This is why I considered recreating the grid, and plotting the fake grid over the lighter color. I tried recreating the grid using 'mark_line', with a fine line, full opacity, and gray color, but strangely the vertical lines got thicker on the "car brands"/columns with more points (even when the thickness of the lines were fixed - but maybe this only happens on very thin lines).